# Problem with recent apps on ubuntu vivid vervet

Tags: testing, unity8

Yesterday I decided to install the testing version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu NEXT 15.04 "Vivid Vervet" because I wanted to test the gorgeous Unity 8 + Mir. But when I first logged in I saw that it had a startup guide. I completed the first part after 2-3 attempts. But I could never complete the second part, which is about recent apps (swipe from right to the left). I don't know why, what I know is that it's very hard to emulate touch with the mouse (true story)! Also on some attempts the screen goes black and comes back again on less than 1/2 second. So is there a secret way to pass it, or even kill it, because I know all the new tricks on Unity 8 + Mir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there currently is no way bypass the intro screen that is giving you troubles.  What you describe seems to have been reported as a bug, and a user has suggested adding "a 'skip intro' button for those of us who can't swipe with our mice."  Please have a look here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1434712

UPDATE:  Comment #7 of the above referenced bug report suggests a temporary workaround that will allow bypassing the intro screen.  I haven't tried the proposed workaround.  I'm waiting for a more permanent fix.

Comment: Wow I didn't knew that this would have happened on many PCs! You know that I have a crappy PC and I thought it was about my PC and also that the intro screen was a separate task from unity8. Also I saw that you commented on this bugs launchpad page and that you downloaded Ubuntu NEXT the same day so we have the same daily  image. More explanations about my computer in my comment on the same bug on lunchpad. I'm the one with the name 'aggelalex' :-D .

Comment: I also saw the comment #7 and I can't wait for this bug to be fixed but I will also wait for a better solution, as I am not so sure for that workaround...

Comment: This was actually fixed long ago, thank you very much m8!